# Using Google Noto fonts with goPdf

Tags: pdf, go, pdf-generation, google-noto

I am trying to use this [Google Noto font](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-thai), but all I'm seeing are squares when I print to pdf. Does anyone know how to add this font to [goPdf](https://github.com/signintech/gopdf)?

Comment: Same problem. Did you ever work it out?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like gopdf supports embedding fonts:

https://godoc.org/github.com/signintech/gopdf#GoPdf.AddTTFFont

Answer (score 0):

GoPdf support only embedding `.ttf` font.

Example:

```
gp := gopdf.GoPdf{}
...
gp.AddTTFFont("fontname","./fonts/fontfile.ttf") //add font
...
gp.SetFont("fontname","",14)  //use font
```

Comment: Yes, this is how you add a font, but it doesnt resolve the "Squares" problem. There appears to be some font mapping issue.